# react-native: turn RTL off in one screen

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, internationalization, i18next

I'm trying to add RTL with i18n to my React-native(expo-CLI) app and I have OTP (one Time Password) screen that has a 4-number input.

the problem is when RTL is `true` the input rotates, for example, the OTP is 4378, when the user types the OTP to the input the result shown is 8734, is there any way I can turn off RTL on this screen?

screenshot when RTL is OFF:
[image]

screenshot when RTL is On:
[image]

I tried the `I18nManager.allowRTL(false)` and did not work